# execute permissions on fuse/fat filesystem

Tags: file-system

I've successfully cross-compiled Ruby for Android and everything goes ok in the emulator.

But while I'm testing these funny things on my device (Nexus4) I noticed that `/sdcard` (or `/storage/emulated/0`) is a fuse mount with no execution permissions.

How can I execute something on the SD card?

I saw that on Linux you can pass it as argument to the linker. In Android this does not work: `/system/bin/linker` wants a pointer to a special struct. I believe that I can write a small C program that creates that structure and run the linker to execute a readable program.

But what about shared libraries? Ruby load tens of shared libraries (every time you have a "require"), I bet that execute permissions are required for loading shared libraries.

Moving the executable to `/data/data/my.app.name/files/` or any other place is not a solution, my binaries are very fat (statically linked) and users should be free to specify any location where storing them.

Comment: This rather seems to be a programming problem, not an Android problem.

Comment: @AlE. why? it's a programming problem if /sdcard has no execution permissions?
btw, i think that the solution is in the kernel, i have to find the way to get the list `struct fuse` from the kernel...

Answer (score 1):

i found a workaround/hack to list them.

when you open a file on the mountpoint the fuse FS handler will open it too.

i used this information and i wrote a small C program that use proc to find source directories.

if you are interested the [project is hosted on github](https://github.com/tux-mind/fusemounts).

regards, tux_mind.